# Create multiple Azure Storage Account with Multiple FileShare under each Storage Account

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-storage-account, terraform-template-file

I am trying to create multiple Azure Storage accounts with specific Azure File shares under each account using the variable type as map:object. I have created the following terraform code but getting the error message:

- **CODE**

```
StorageAccount = {
  "dev" = {
    SName       = "test"
    SAFileShare = [logs1", "Logs3"]
  }
  "prd" = {
    SName       = "test1"
    SAFileShare = ["Logs3", "logs4"]

  }
}

variable "StorageAccount" {
  type = map(object({
    SName       = string
    SAFileShare = list(string)
    SABlob      = list(string)
  }))
}


# Storage Account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "Storage" {
  for_each                 = var.StorageAccount
  name                     = lower(join("", [var.AppShortName, join(each.value["SName"], [var.EnvironmentType, "sa"])]))
  location                 = var.Location
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.ResourceGroup.name
  account_tier             = var.accountTier
  account_replication_type = var.accountReplicationType
}

# File Share 
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "FileShare" {
  for_each             = var.StorageAccount
  name                 = each.value["SAFileShare"]
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.Storage[each.key].name
  quota                = 50
}
```

- **Error Message**

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 4, in resource "azurerm_storage_share" "FileShare":
│    4:   name                 = each.value["SAFileShare"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value["SAFileShare"] is list of string with 2 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.
```

Comment: Your variable input values contain a syntax error. Is this MCVE accurate?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to Create multiple Azure Storage Account with Multiple FileShare under each Storage Account using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully

You are getting this error because of how you are creating the Azure File Shares. The `name` attribute of the `azurerm_storage_share` resource requires a string, but you are giving it a list of strings with `each.value["SAFileShare"]`. Terraform will not create multiple file shares by looping over this list automatically.

I was having trouble with the `for_each` expression and the dynamic property, so I tried this solution, which seems to meet the requirement for now.

**My demo terraform configruation:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "demorg-vkvk"  # Replace with your resource group name
}

variable "location" {
  type    = string
  default = "East US"  # Replace with your preferred location
}

variable "storage_accounts" {
  description = "List of storage account names"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["storageaccountvk1", "storageaccountvk2"]  # Replace with your unique storage account names
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  for_each                = toset(var.storage_accounts)
  name                    = each.value
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier            = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "file_share1" {
  count                 = length(var.storage_accounts)
  name                  = "${var.storage_accounts[count.index]}-fileshare1"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account[var.storage_accounts[count.index]].name
  quota                 = 50
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "file_share2" {
  count                 = length(var.storage_accounts)
  name                  = "${var.storage_accounts[count.index]}-fileshare2"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account[var.storage_accounts[count.index]].name
  quota                 = 50
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. My objective is not to use counter and generate the sequential storage account. We need to provision two storage accounts where the first will have 2 file share as input and output and the second storage account will have a 3 file shares as frontend, backend and database. we need to achieve this by using the single resource block of storage account and file share using the for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use merge function for looping twice in map of objects.
here's what you can do:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "FileShare" {
for_each             = merge([ for sa_key, sa_value in var.StorageAccount: { for val in sa_value["SAFileShare"] : val => sa_key }]...)
name                 = each.key
storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.Storage[each.value].name
quota                = 50
}
```

This can be used to create multiple file share in certain storage accounts as you wanted.